# Redirect after form submission instead of the message after reCaptcha implementation

Tags: html, node.js, recaptcha

I implemented recaptcha on my web site and started getting redirect to the mysite.com/send-email page after form submission instead of displaying the message on the form/main page. I added a text to the message to understand where does it come from and it does display "Message successfully sent from Server msg". Meaning the form.js doesn't handle the response as expected. I beat both CGPT and Bard to death but can't find the solution. The display message would pop-up before I implemented captcha but can't find what's wrong in the code now:
From the server.js:

```
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
            if (error) {                
                res.status(500).send('Error sending email: ' + error.message);
            } else {
                res.send('Email sent successfully from Server msg');
            }
        });
```

From the form.js:

```
        // Submit the form using AJAX.
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: $(form).attr('action'),
            data: formData
        })
        .done(function(response) {
            // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'success' class.
            $('#form-messages').removeClass('bg-danger');
            $('#form-messages').addClass('bg-success');

            // Set the message text.
            $('#form-messages').text('Your message successfully sent from Form msg');

            // Clear the form.
            $('#name, #email, #message').val('');           
        })
```

And from the index.html:

```
<form> xxxx </form>
<div id="form-messages" class="mt-3"></div>
```

The confirmation msg on the same page instead of a redirect

Comment: I isolated the issue and it looks like there is a conflict how the server's response is being handled by AJAX in case there is CAPTCHA integrated. Me, Bard and CGPT got into loop without finding a way how to fix this. A possible solution might be hard coding a redirect to a temporary page saying "Your response is received" and then redirecting back to the main site.